# Asking for name again if the first name input doesn't match the second name input

Tags: java, input, bufferedreader

I would like to make a program that asks the user his name two times. If the two names are the same regardless of the case, it will print success. If the two names are not the same, it will ask the user again to input another set of names (2 names) and if it is now the same it will also print success.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Enter name: ");
    String one = input.readLine();
    System.out.println("Enter name: ");
    String two = input.readLine();
        
    if (one.equalsIgnoreCase(two)) {
        System.out.print("Success");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Enter name: ");
        input.readLine();
        System.out.println("Eneter name: ");
        input.readLine();
    }
}
```

The part that checks if the two names are the same is fine. The part that I am confused is the code where it will ask for another set of 2 names

```
else {
    System.out.println("Enter name: ");
    input.readLine();
    System.out.println("Eneter name: ");
    input.readLine();
}
```

**Example output:**

```
Enter name:
Mark Andrew
Enter name:
Mark Andrew
Success
```

```
Enter name:
Mark Andrew
Enter name:
John Paul
Enter name:
Mark Andrew
Enter name:
Mark Andrew
//this is the part that I am confused. It doesn't print success//
```

I am open to opinions and suggestions.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the **else** part, you are not checking again if the names are the same or not. That's why it's not showing Success the next time when you gave the same names. Using a loop would be better if we want to take inputs until the same names are entered.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    boolean areNamesEqual = false;
    while(!areNamesEqual) {
        System.out.println("Enter name: ");
        String one = input.readLine();
        System.out.println("Re-enter name: ");
        String two = input.readLine();
        if (one.equalsIgnoreCase(two)) {
            areNamesEqual = true;               
        }
    }
    System.out.print("Success");
}
```

Comment: But what if I want to use the first if instead?

Comment: What I want to do is to make it so that every time I input to different names it will keep asking me to input another set of name until I input two same names. Then If I input two same names it will print success.

Comment: Then use a loop if you want to compare the names until the same names are entered the first and second time. Please look at the updated code.